# Integral over a sequence of sets whose measures $\to 0.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $ f \in L_p$ with $1 \leq p \leq \infty $ and ${A_n}$ is a sequence of measurable sets such that $ \mu (An) \rightarrow 0,$ then $ \int_{A_n} f \rightarrow 0$.

Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: Can you do it when $p=1$?

Comment: You may consider DCT and $\{f(x)>N\}$.

Comment: @zhw. Yes, I am able to show this when p=1. But I don't think that will work for the rest.

Comment: @BrianDing I don't see how that can work right now, but I'll work on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\left|\int_{A_n}f d\mu \right| = \left|\int_{A_n}f\cdot 1 d\mu \right|\le \int_{A_n}|f|\cdot 1 d\mu \le \left(\int_{A_n}|f|^pd\mu\right)^{1/p}(\mu (A_n))^{1/q}\le \|f\|_p(\mu (A_n))^{1/q}$$

Comment: This might be obvious for must of us, however I think you should mention that you are applying Hölder's inequality.

Comment: So $p=1$ needs a separate proof as you said.

Answer (score 1):

My proof might be a bit lengthy but I think it might be a more standard way in dealing with this kind of problem.

First by $f\in L^{p}$ and DCT ($f_n= |f|^p 1_{\{|f|>n\}}\leq |f|, f_n\rightarrow 0$ a.e. as $f \in L^p$ ), we have

$$\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N >1 , s.t. \int_{\{|f|>N\}} |f|^p <\epsilon/2.$$

Now since $|f|^p>f$ on $\{|f|>N\}$,$$|\int_{A_n}f |\leq \int_{\{A_n,\; |f|>N\}}|f| + \int_{\{A_n,\;|f|\leq N\}}|f| \leq \int_{\{|f|> N\}}|f|^p +N\mu(A_n)\leq \epsilon/2 + N\mu(A_n).$$

Since $N$ depends on $\epsilon$, you can chose $A_n$ small enough ($\epsilon/2N$)so that 
$$|\int_{A_n}f |\leq \epsilon.$$